# Linux on-the-fly block data verification

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raspberry-pi

I am quite used to a parity compare/scrub feature of many of the NAS systems. However, I am failing to find similar feature when it comes to single hard drives. Of course, with a single drive there will be no way to actually know if a bit is correct, however, it should be at least possible to detect unreadable sectors and know when a disk needs to be de-commissioned.

My use case scenario:

- single external hdd connected to a linux box
- weekly test "scrub" to ensure that we are not hitting bad sectors

Furthermore, if there was a way to do anything similar to SpinRite online on the disk, that would be ideal (but probably problematic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern disks often do bad block detection and relocation in firmware.  By the time you see them, the disk is likely almost unusable.  The usually provide SMART capabilities which allow you to query the data which will indicate failure in impending.

Look for packages like `smartmontools`, `smart-notifier`, or `smartctl`.

Comment: Yes, but that happens only when data is accessed - what if it just sits there for a year corrupted without anybody noticing? That's why I am suggesting at least a read, to alert the underlying firmware of any potential errors

Comment: @petr You can just use `dd` to read the whole disk to the bit bucket, or use `find` and `xargs` to read used blocks.  If you are doing backups, then data will be read reasonably often.  I believe most disks use read after write to detect corruption at write time,  do blocks shouldn't be sitting around corrupted.